# Write Data from Matlab to a Text File

Tags: matlab, file-io

I need to save multiple arrays to a text file in the following format:

> n=2 %number of arrays
>
> r=3 %number of rows in the first array 
> 1 2 3 % actual data 
> 4 5 6 
> 7 8 9 
>
>
> r=3 %number of rows in the second array 
> 5 6 7 % actual data 
> 1 2 3 
> 7 8 9

Would you help please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [fprintf](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/fprintf.html). If your arrays are stored in a cell array so that you can iterate through them.

```
arrays = cell(N, 1); %A cell array of arrays

f = fopen('output.txt', 'w');
fprintf(f, 'n=%i\n', N);

for i=1:N
  rows = size(arrays{i}, 1);
  fprintf(f, '\nr=%i\n', rows);
  for j=1:rows
    fprintf(f, '%g ', arrays{i}(N, :));
    fprintf(f, '\n');
  end
end
fclose(f);
```

Answer (score 1):

What have you done so far?

As a general rule, for this sort of thing your friends are the functions [fprintf](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/fprintf.html), which prints data to a file, and [varargin](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/varargin.html), which allows you to supply a variable-length argument list to a function. A good signature for a function that handles this sort of task might therefore be

```
function [output_args] = pretty_save_to_file(fName, varargin)
```

Here `fName` is the name of the file you'd like your data saved to and `varargin` is a placeholder for the names of the matrices you'd like to save. Once you've filled in the gory details of the function, you should be able to call it using something like

```
pretty_save_to_file('output.txt', A, B, C) % prints matrices A, B, and C to output.txt
```

In addition, since you're looking to determine the number of rows in each matrix, you'll probably find the following snippet involving the [size](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/size.html) function useful:

```
[nrows, ncols] = size(A); % Stores the number of rows and columns of A in nrows, ncols
```

Finally, the fprintf function allows you to specify the desired formatting of your matrix.